# Max WCF message size exception even though it is configured

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I am getting this exception:

> The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element

My app.config is as follows:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
  <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IContentServiceController" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
  <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAbstractServiceController" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
  <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISecurityServiceController" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />        
</basicHttpBinding>
```

Comment: There is no question here.

Comment: I had the same issue I managed it in code behind using like `BasicHttpBinding bhb = new BasicHttpBinding();
            bhb.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue;`

Answer (score 0):

On client side:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Service" allowCookies="false" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
        closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
    </binding>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:80/Service.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Service" contract="WCF.IService"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

On server side:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Service" allowCookies="false" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
                      maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>    
  </bindings>
  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="WCF.ServiceBehavior" name="WCF.Service">
      <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Service" contract="WCF.IService">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost"/>
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="WCF.ServiceBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Make sure they both have bindings configure for maximum quotas values.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you've defined bindings with maximum quotas, they won't take effect unless you assign the binding(s) to a specified endpoint - the default values for the binding will be used.  Without seeing the other relevant sections of the config file's `<system.serviceModel>`, you need to either a) assign the binding to a specific endpoint via the `bindingConfiguration` attribute or b) set it as the default binding (for .NET 4.0 and later).

Since you have 3 bindings defined (all for `basicHttpBinding`) option b may not be suitable (you can only have one default definition per binding), so option a would look something like this (for the service):

```
<services>
  <service name="myService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IContentServiceController" contract="MyService.IContentServiceController" />
  </service>
</services>
```

The client would look very similar:

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://someaddress/" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IContentServiceController" contract="MyService.IContentServiceController" />
</client>
```